# Deleting empty spaces from the header of a data frame using r

Tags: r, subset

I want to remove the white spaces from the header of a dataframe in R but I don't know how to subset the header only.
My dataframe is of the tipe of df given by the following code:

```
a <- c("a", "b")
b  <- c(20, 30)
head  <- c("d area", "f area")
df  <- data.frame(a,b)
names(df) <- head
```

what I would like to have is a dataframe with modified header so that to get rid of empty spaces, so the result will be a dataframe like the newdf given by the following code:

```
a <- c("a", "b")
b  <- c(20, 30)
head  <- c("darea", "farea")
df  <- data.frame(a,b)
names(df) <- head
```

Thank you very much for your help

Giulia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
colnames(df) <- gsub(" ","",colnames(df))
```

Comment: because OP didn't specify that only the first space needs to be removed

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! is exactly what I wanted. 

thank you
Giulia

Answer (score 4):

If you use `data.frame`, you get the intervention of the `make.names` function:

```
 df <- data.frame(df)
```

OR:

```
 names(df) <- make.names(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using the package `stringr`

```
 library(stringr)
 names(df) <- str_replace_all(string=names(df), pattern=" ", repl="")
```